# Import specific rows and formulas from master sheet

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I have been looking for hours now how to solve my problem, as it follows :

I want to duplicate [this master sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hwZCXxC_beJ7mWas0Wl5bUcOw7l7sm3NrO9Czk1oCs4/edit?usp=sharing) a hundred times and be able to let [the end-users](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hApKeiuG9xbL5szkS3MOIRM7vww5RrkG5gwtPpGWzio/edit?usp=sharing) fill in the green cells, without breaking the `IMPORTRANGE` formula (cell `A3`).

Also keeping  the original formulas (additions and multiplications) of the master sheet within the copied sheets would be a great plus.

I have tried multi things with `QUERY` formulas but I just can't sort it out.

Thanks in advance to anyone helping out !

Comment: *"Thanks in advance to anyone helping out !"* Have you tried the given solution? Did it work for you? If not we should try finding out why. If yes, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

1. Make a copy of tab `Feuille 1`

*The rest of the steps are all in this copied tab.*

2. In cell `A3` place the formula

```
=IMPORTRANGE("1hwZCXxC_beJ7mWas0Wl5bUcOw7l7sm3NrO9Czk1oCs4";"Feuille 1!A3:R7")
```

3. In cell `A14` place:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("1hwZCXxC_beJ7mWas0Wl5bUcOw7l7sm3NrO9Czk1oCs4";"Feuille 1!A14:R20")
```

4. Manually fill in the values for cells `A8`, `A9-R9`, `A11-B11`.
5. Go to `Data` >> `Protected sheets and ranges` and lock the sheet **except cells `B8-R8`**.
6. Delete the first sheet keeping just the copy.
7. Make 100 copies of your TEST sheet.
8. Enjoy :)